# Request.ServerVariables - Where has it gone?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to get the data that was in Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"] in an API controller in ASP.Net Web Api. But the servervariables dictionary is gone. 
Is that property/data still available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Request.ServerVariables` is there or not on the hosting medium that you have. Simply use `Request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"].Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]` to get what you need.